# Vue watch issue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have two pages and I can change the same vuex value from both of them
On the first page(main page) I watch the vuex value and send a request when it changes

```
const selectedPokemonType = computed(() => store.getters.getPokemonType) // selectedPokemonType: {[key: string]: string}`

watch(selectedPokemonType.value, () => {
  getPokemonsByType(selectedPokemonType.value.typeName).then(
    ({ data: { pokemon } }) =>
      store.commit(Mutations.SAVE_POKEMONS_BY_TYPE_TO_STORE, pokemon)
  )
})
```

If I change vuex value from first page - everything works well
On second page I change vuex value and also change vue-route to main page

```
const onTypeClick = (data: { [key: string]: string }) => {
  store.commit(Mutations.SAVE_SELECTED_TYPE_TO_STORE, data)
  router.go(-1) // or router.push('/')
}
```

As result: now I'm on main page but watcher doesn't re-send request but there is a new value in vuex

P.S. Sorry if the question seems stupid, I just started learning vue

Everything I can....

Comment: Your watch doe not work. Watch souce (the first argument of watch function) can be a refs, reactive object, getter function or an array of multiple sources (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watch-source-types). So, in your case, is is a value not a ref.
solution:
- remove the **.value** on **watch(selectedPokemonType.value,**
- or change it to getter like this: **watch(() => selectedPokemonType.value,**

Answer (score 1):

Your watch source is not a valid [watch wource type](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watch-source-types). Here is the solution.

```js
const selectedPokemonType = computed(() => store.getters.getPokemonType)

watch(() => selectedPokemonType.value, () => {
  getPokemonsByType(selectedPokemonType.value.typeName).then(
    ({ data: { pokemon } }) =>
      store.commit(Mutations.SAVE_POKEMONS_BY_TYPE_TO_STORE, pokemon)
  )
})
```

Or:

```js
const selectedPokemonType = computed(() => store.getters.getPokemonType)

watch(selectedPokemonType, () => {
  getPokemonsByType(selectedPokemonType.value.typeName).then(
    ({ data: { pokemon } }) =>
      store.commit(Mutations.SAVE_POKEMONS_BY_TYPE_TO_STORE, pokemon)
  )
})
```

Or event better in your case:

```js
const selectedPokemonType = computed(() => store.getters.getPokemonType)

watchEffect(() => {
  getPokemonsByType(selectedPokemonType.value.typeName).then(
    ({ data: { pokemon } }) =>
      store.commit(Mutations.SAVE_POKEMONS_BY_TYPE_TO_STORE, pokemon)
  )
})
```